# Получение аргументов из команды Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Вообщем-то, простенький фидбек бот(с отправкой сообщений(копирование и отправка) в обе стороны)
При отправке через команду, бот пересылает сообщение вместе с командой, т.е `/send bla bla bla`
Каким образом можно удалить команду  из сообщения?

убрал код в связи с решением, спасибо большое.

Comment: Может хотя бы код бота отправите? **Не** в комментарии, если вы всё же захотели отправить код то просто отредактируйте вопрос где и добавите код, отредактировать вопрос можно кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1458568/edit).

Comment: Пускай вопрос будет, он кому-то еще пригодится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот. К примеру `/send 123`

```
@dp.message_handler(commands="send")
async def start(msg: types.Message):
    result = msg.get_args() # <- 123
```